How to independently run a DLL file written C# (without rundll32.exe) to debug with dnSpy
I want to debug a dll written in c# but being a dll I don't know how to run it independently so I can attack dnspy. I thought of writing 2 lines to import the dll and call a function but the metadata is intentionally corrupted because the file is packed with confuserEX and my intent is to be able to execute the dll so I can dump from memory after .cctor() has unpacked the PE but I need help because I have no idea how to do it
Googling I found a way to use rundll32 by modifying the export table but in this case it doesn't help me
